# Regex to match words that have an upper case character not in 1st pos, and some lower case chars

Tags: r, regex

My text contains terms that are pasted to each other, luckily the pasted terms mostly start with upper case.

The strings I want to match will contain at least one word which contains at least one lower case character AND at least one upper case character that wouldn't be the first one.

Please see below for the diverse cases I should handle.

```
my_corpus <- c("PleaseMatch this",
"And alsoThis",
"this ASWell",
"thisTOO",
"Though NOT THIS",
"Nor This")

rgx <- "..." # please help me here

grep(rgx ,my_corpus) # 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Try `"[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]|\\B[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]"`. It would help if you could formulate the rules in words.

Comment: So, [`[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]|[[:alpha:]][[:upper:]][[:lower:]]`](https://regex101.com/r/iiIiek/1) will be better, right?

Comment: Thanks, they both work for me. Your first suggestion seems better because it matches all 3 items from `c("1Aa","A1Aa","a1Aa")` while your second option matches none. `"a1A"` is matched by none of your suggestions but in practice I don't need it. I'll accept your answer if you care to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider the following solution:

```
[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]|\B[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ecHkLw/1).

Or, if `Foo_Bar` should not be matched (note the `\B` non-word boundary will match an uppercase letter after `_`):

```
[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:upper:]][[:lower:]]
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/KrfyGa/1).

Or, to also handle `a1A` case:

```
[[:lower:]][[:upper:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:upper:]][[:lower:]]|[0-9][[:upper:]]\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eXty0A/1).

**Details**:

- `[[:lower:]]` - matches a lowercase letter
- `[[:upper:]]` - matches an uppercase letter
- `|`  - an alternation operator (separates alternatives in one group)
- `[[:alnum:]]` - matches an alphanumeric char
- `[0-9]` - matches any ASCII digit (you may use `[[:digit:]]`, too)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\B` - a non-word boundary.